# Routing Issue after upgrading to ionic-framework 2.0.0-alpha.57 (Ionic 2)

Tags: mobile, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been working on bringing some Ionic 2 applications, that were written by another developer during the early Ionic 2 Alpha, up to date with the most recent beta release.

I've run into an issue with `2.0.0-alpha.57`, which requires removal of web-animations.js from webpack.config.js. Since removing this file, clicking an element on my app's main page no longer navigates to a new page. I can see in the Chrome device debugger that the click is registered, and the app's state is changed, but there is no change visible to the user. Additionally, once an element has been clicked, the page becomes unresponsive.

I'll attach a picture of the state of the app after clicking on the first list element (Taxi). Ideally, the click would result in the user being navigated to a new page. The two errors at the bottom of the JS console appear once an element has been clicked.

[image]

As far as I can tell the following code is executed when an element is clicked:

```
public GotoDetails(event, expenseType) {
    this._nav.push(AddExpensePage, { "ExpenseType": expenseType });
}
```

Is anyone aware of a known issue regarding this file and routing?

Thanks,

Matt